# Do you know more efficient way to create this python list?

Tags: python, list, performance

So, I know that is super simple, but I don't have idea how to found the answer in google :<

It would be grate if you could tell me how I can optimalize this, or just let me know how this type of list is called.

The function takes one argument "n" and return list of numbers from 1 to "n" and every number appends "n" times

```
def my_function(n):
    x = []
    y = 1
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            x.append(y)
        y += 1
    return x

my_function(3)
```

Should return : **[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]**

Comment: What do you mean by "more efficient"? Smaller compute time? What's the real problem setup you are facing? Computing `[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]` seems pretty simple.

Comment: Use a list comprehension. The conversion from this loop is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one simple way with no extra libraries involved:

```
def my_function(n):
    # returns array from 1 to n+1 (e.g. if n=3, x=[1,2,3])
    x = list(range(1, n+1))

    # create a new array with every element of x repeated n times
    # Returns x = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
    x = x * n

    # Sort all elements of x to group them
    # Returns x = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
    x.sort()

    return x

my_function(3)
```

With no comments/combined, it would just be:

```
def my_function(n):
    x = list(range(1, n+1))* n
    x.sort()
    return x
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean smaller like this?

```
def foo(n):
    result = []
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        result += ([i]*n)
    return result

foo(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner pythonic way:

```
def foo(n):
    return [i for i in range(1, n+1) for _ in range(n)]

foo(3)
```